# How to add .toCurrency in all numeric values in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can't say I tried everything as I am not too much in to ASP.NET. I even tried googling but I was unsure what to search.

I haev several classes in ASP.NET as I am making a billing software for a reputed PSU. The project is deployed and is working fine.

Now the client requires the numbers in the bills to be currency formatted in reports but to be unformatted (numeric) in certain other things.

As I already have classes which have exposed property as double, I want my developers to give something very easy so that they can do it rapidly.

Something like : `myclassobj.EnergyBillAmount().toCurreny("en-IN")` or something like this.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using `double` for financial values in the first place? That's a bad idea - you should generally be using `decimal` for that.

Comment: May I know the reason for the down vote? If it's the double case. It's a requirement from the client's IT team. We suggested them about the decimal thing and they said "NO, MAKE IT DOUBLE". :) :( helpless.

Comment: @KumarRavi: Then your client either has too much money or he doesn't care about it. Use `double` only for things which are inaccurate by nature(f.e. length specifications).

Comment: Yes actually they have turnover more than 7 billion dollars quarterly (as I already mentioned it's a government entity - PSU) controlling the Power Sector (GRID) of India. And they raise monthly bills of around 1 billion to theirs beneficiaries or states)

Comment: Can't see any reason to downvote though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)

Create a class as below

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static int ToCurrency(this Int val)
        {
            //Code logic
        }
    }   
}
```

And do a

```
using ExtensionMethods;
```

where you want to call it

and use like

```
int s = 100;
int i = s.ToCurrency();
```

Hope it helps....

Answer (score 2):

All you need is [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx)

```
public static class FormatExtensions
{
     public static string ToCurrency(this double value, string culture)
     {
         //return converted value
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) for that.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `double` you should use `decimal` for currency.

Do you really need an [extension method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) for this:

```
string c = 1234.56m.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-IN"));
```

Result: `₹ 1,234.56`

Comment: Well, not actually answer to my question but a nice little way to do it. Great! Thanks.

Comment: @KumarRavi: Well, i've seen that people already showed how to create an extension(just in case i've added the link), so i thought that you were doing things too complicated if you need to ask for such an extension.

Answer (score 0):

```
myclassobj.EnergyBillAmount().ToString("C2", yourCulture);
```

Comment: Well, not actually answer to my question but a nice little way to do it. Great! Thanks.